# Client connects but won't play music in Discord Voice Channel

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make my bot play music in a member's VC, but all it does is download the song the member tries to play, join the voice channel, and immediately goes to my `dispatcher.on("end", () => {})` function. The path to the song is correct. If I try to play the song directly on Windows it works, but the bot doesn't even play anything. I have FFmpeg installed, installed node-opus using `yarn add node-opus` and I honestly have no clue why it doesn't work.

```
message.member.voiceChannel.join()
  .then(connection => {
    const dispatcher = connection.playFile('C:\Users\ameij\OneDrive\programming\promo\ytdl\song.mp3');
    dispatcher.on("end", () => {
      this.message.channel.send('Finished Playing.')
      dispatcher.end();

      this.message.member.voiceChannel.leave();
    })
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error because I did not have ffmpeg installed globally.

Try to do `npm i -g ffmpeg-binaries`, maybe you hadn't installed ffmpeg globally (Sorry I should comment but I have not enough reputation)

If that does not work, try to install node-opus again using NPM: `npm i node-opus`